# How many times does a subset appear in all the variations of the whole set?

Tags: combinatorics

**Scenario**

- I have four red balls.
- And I have six white balls.

I want to create an aligned set of three balls.

There are many different ways of positioning three of those balls in a line, if I consider each ball is unique, not attending to its color.

Knowing that there are ten balls, and I take three of them, there are 10*9*8=720 ways.

**Question**

What would be the smartest way to calculate how many of those 720 variations contain exactly n red balls - considering all balls and all positions in the line are different?

**Note**: Red1|White1|White2 is not supposed to be the same as Red1|White2|White1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break this process into three steps:

1. Choose the $n$ red balls.  There are $\binom{4}{n}$ ways of doing this.
2. Choose the $3-n$ white balls.  There are $\binom{6}{3-n}$ ways of doing this.
3. Order the $3$ chosen balls.  There are $3!$ ways to do this.

This gives a total of
$$ \binom{4}{n} \binom{6}{3-n} 3! $$
ways to line up $3$ balls, with exactly $n$ of them being red.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank You.

Comment: Awww shucks, you're welcome!